# Pasting into web evernote appears double-spaced from OSX Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, clipboard, atom-editor, evernote

On osx I want to copy output on terminal screen to evernote.com (the web version). I can do that, but it appears double-spaced.

However, if I take the same terminal output and instead paste into another editor, say Atom, then copy that same text from Atom and back into Evernote (the web version), the text appears normally spaced.

What's up???

Opening chrome developer tools, shows in the double-spaced case, the text is surrounded by paragraph tags, <p>, but in the normal case, the text is surrounded by line break, <br>, tags.

Is the problem some setting in Terminal, the clipboard itself, or Evernote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't know about right-clicking within Evernote to paste content, as [akhaku](https://stackexchange.com/users/379572/akhaku) mentioned, so tried that, found no plain text option, but the "Paste and Match Style" did the trick.

[Here's an image capture from the web interface to Evernote.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpV8r.png)

Notice the top half appears double-spaced.  This was done with a simple copy (highlight with mouse then copy via Command-C) in the OSX terminal into Evernotes' web editor via OSX paste (Command-V).

The bottom half shows the result after right-clicking instead within Evernote, and choosing "Paste and Match Style".

[Snapshot of results of pastes into Evernote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpV8r.png)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

It may be pasting with formatting, try right clicking and paste as plaintext or paste without formatting. FWIW the web version currently uses [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) as the editor.